# List Comprehensions, Scoping and Lambdas in Python

Tags: python, lambda, scope, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

Let's say I want a family of functions `f[0], f[1], ... f[9]` such that `f[y](x) = x + 2 * y`.

To achieve this, I try the following list comprehension:

```
fs = [(lambda x : x + 2 * y) for y in range(10)]
```

However, this does not work at all. For example, `fs[0](2)` evaluates to `20`, instead of the desired `4`.

What is going on here? Is this some strange scoping issue?

I have also tried things like `[(lambda x: x + 2 * y) for y in the list(range(10))]` but none of this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`y` may be the last value it was set to

Set it as a default argument to the lambda

```py
[(lambda x, _y=y : x + 2 * _y) for y in range(10)]
```